# Does having more gyms give more stardust?

Tags: pokemon-go

I was told that even if you hold 3 gyms you still get 500 Stardust, though you do get 30 coins. Since I've been unable to  control more than one gym at a time, I've been unable to confirm this.

Does having more gyms equate to more stardust?

Comment: you'd get 1500 stardust, maybe they just missed the "1" and only saw "500"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get 500 stardust and 10 coins per gym, up to a cap of 10 gyms (for a total cap of 5000 dust and 100 coins).